# Mobile Chrome and height-dependent sizing & scroll

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, mobile-chrome

In my recent project I am using element that are using percentage heights. It works well on most browsers, however, it creates unwanted behaviour in Chrome Mobile.

In a nutshell - when a user scrolls up, the address bar becomes visible. This changes the height of the screen, which forces the elements to resize. As this happens after the scroll ends, the user sees a "jump" after the scroll stops.

Is there any way to avoid this behaviour and still use elements sized with the viewport percentage?

Comment: Is there a way you can screenshot this and produce some code. "Address bar" sounds to me like the browser address bar. Which is a browser issue not something you can alter.

Comment: Yes, this is related to the mobile Chrome. What it does is that when you scroll up, the address bar scrolls with the content. This increases visible height of the viewport, which means that my content also responds, which changes document length.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can fix this problem with css. Just use @media queries like that:

```
@media only screen
    and (min-device-width: 320px) //here is your condition for the screen
    and (max-device-width: 568px){

    .class{
        height: 80%;
    }
}
```

You can have as many media-queries as you need. Please note that you may need to edit the min-device-width or/and max-device-width to your needs. Depends on the device.

Comment: thank you for this - but I am trying to avoid the need to specify a large number of screen sizes, it is just not feasible with the variety present out there. Your solution would be a last-resort for me I would think

Comment: Well, then this might be a problem as this is the only way to ensure that everything is working correctly on the desired screen size. But if you find another version, let me know.

Comment: You can control the scope of the specificity. Cascade a parent class in front of .class that has a more global scope and it will happen on a larger amount of screen that satisfy that requirement.